# Image of $\gamma-1$ on etale $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-modules

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $p\geq 3$ be a prime, $D$ be an etale $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-modules over the classical period ring $A_{\mathbb{Q}_p}=\mathbb{Z}_p[\![T]\!][1/T]^{\widehat{\phantom{xx}}}_p$ and $\gamma$ be a topological generator of the Galois group $\Gamma=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{cycl}}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$. How much do we know about the image $(\gamma-1)D$?

Let us consider the simplest case: the trival $\bmod p$ $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-module $D=\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}=\mathbb{F}_p(\!(\pi)\!)$, where $\pi=\varepsilon-1$, $\varepsilon=(\zeta_{p^n})_{n\geq 1}\in\mathbb{C}_p^\flat$. We may write any element $x$ of $\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ as $x=\sum_{n\geq n_0}a_n\pi^n$. It can be shown that for any positive $n$, $\pi^n\in(\gamma-1)D$. But this does not hold for non-positive $n$. The inverse of $\pi^n$ w.r.t. $\gamma-1$ with $n<0$ can be formally constructed, but it does not exist in $\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. On the other hand, $(\gamma-1)\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ does consist of many elements with negative degree terms, for example, $$(\gamma-1)\pi^{-1}=\frac{1}{(\pi+1)^{\chi(\gamma)}-1}-\frac{1}{\pi}\in (\gamma-1)\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}.$$

So what can we say more than $(\gamma-1)D$ contains all finite $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear combination of $\pi^n$, with $n=1,2,\ldots$? Or, equivalently, how can we determine whether an element of $\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ lies in the image of $\gamma-1$ or not?

Comment: Since $D$ is an etale $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-module, there is the usual map $\psi$ on $D$. By a theorem of Herr, $1-\gamma$ is bijective on $D^{\psi=0}$. So the image of $1-\gamma$ contains $D^{\psi=0}$, and also $\varphi^n(D^{\psi=0})$ for all $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Take $x \in D$. You can write $x=(x-\varphi\psi(x)) + (\varphi\psi(x) - \varphi^2\psi^2(x)) + \cdots + (\varphi^{n-1}\psi^{n-1}(x)- \varphi^n\psi^n(x)) + \varphi^n\psi^n(x)$. Each term is in the image of $1-\gamma$ by the above comment, except $\varphi^n\psi^n(x)$. And in characteristic $p$, $\psi$ tends to lower denominators as you iterate it. This should help reducing the problem of computing the image.

Comment: Conversely, take $D=\mathrm{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Power series have residues, and $\mathrm{res}(\gamma(f) \cdot d\pi / (1+\pi)) = \chi(\gamma)^{-1} \mathrm{res} (f \cdot d\pi / (1+\pi))$. This will give you necessary conditions for an element to be in the image of $1-\gamma$.

Comment: @LaurentBerger Thank you. I'm aware of the $\psi$-operator (you may know what I am doing :-P). I'm just curious whether the image of $\gamma-1$ can somehow be described explicitly (which seems to be difficult).